# How do I change counter cart in a storefront woocommerce?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change counter cart so that it displays 0 as empty and delete the word "item". I am using storefront 2.2.5 template in plug-in woocommerce 3.2.0. Where are the files responsible for this code? It will probably need to change something in jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the function which do that. file `storefront/inc/woocommerce/storefront-woocommerce-template-functions.php`

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'storefront_cart_link' ) ) {
    /**
     * Cart Link
     * Displayed a link to the cart including the number of items present and the cart total
     *
     * @return void
     * @since  1.0.0
     */
    function storefront_cart_link() {
        ?>
            <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'View your shopping cart', 'storefront' ); ?>">
                <span class="amount"><?php echo wp_kses_data( WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal() ); ?></span> <span class="count"><?php echo wp_kses_data( sprintf( _n( '%d item', '%d items', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(), 'storefront' ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ) );?></span>
            </a>
        <?php
    }
}
```

You will need to define the function in your child theme's `functions.php` file, or in a `plugin`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not a solution to my problem. I want to change the existing shopping cart but I am not good enough with jquery. I can't find the part of the code responsible for displaying count and "items".

Comment: You could also hack the translation entries. but that's not really a solution.  

I think that if you define `storefront_cart_link` in your `functions.php` to what you need, this would make it as woocommerce make ajax calls and insert the returned html.   

It's php that write it, i think it's in php where it should be made.

Please share more infos so i could suggest better.

Comment: I think that I made myself cleary. If the cart shopping is empty. I would like display "0" without word "item".   If there is an item, for example, one item. I would like  display "1" without the word "item"

Comment: Sorry, JBoulhous it works, but I have a really weird problem. My web browser doesn't reload code in this function